# Примеры написания интерпретаторов серверных языков

Tags: веб-сервер, интерпретатор, метапрограммирование

Гугл никак не хочет выдавать по этому запросы точные результаты. Есть ли литература\статьи именно по серверным языкам? Да, мне интересно попробовать свои силы в велосипедостроении.

Comment: Самая известная "книга с драконом" https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/971665 И серверные языки ни чем не отличаются от всех остальных. Особенно если учесть, что "клиентских" языков сейчас вообще не существует. Раньше JS был только в браузерах и его можно было считать клиентским, но сейчас это не так

Comment: Мне все же не понятны многие вещи, например, каким образом происходит передача хедеров в аргументы, как происходит пересылка выходного html. Но, спасибо!

Comment: А причем тут какие то хеадеры и выходной html. Вы даже в вопросе ни слова ни сказали что это как то связано с web. А практически все языки позволяют работать не только с web. И вообще общение клиента и сервера web к языку программирования не имеет никакого отношения. Большинство "серверных" языков, с клиентом по web не работают вообще. Они общаются с web-сервером. Причем в очень простом виде: web-сервер запускает обработчик и на стандартный ввод подает все, что пришло от клиента. А обработчик выдает на стандартный вывод то, что надо отправить клиенту

Comment: Да, мое упущение. То есть, корректно было бы сказать про связь интерпретатора и сервера?

Comment: Возможно. я не знаю что вы хотели на самом деле. Сейчас вопрос касается литературы по написанию собственных языков. Эта тема вообще никак не касается web. С web может работать любой язык общего назначения. Если вы хотите новый язык, через который будет происходить работа с web то это две (и более) независимых тем. Сначала нужно сделать язык. После этого определится как происходит работа с клиентом через web-сервер, как делает подавляющее кол-во языков или напрямую (NodeJS). для 1-го почитать про CGI. для 2-го про написание собственного web-сервера. И там и там полезно почитать про HTTP

Comment: Спасибо! Да, это то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то давно, когда еще деревья были большими, а 640 кБ ОЗУ хватало всем, мне понадобился скриптовой язык для написания тестовых скриптов. Никакого Питона тогда не было и я написал интерпретатор Basic. Думаю, что в качестве примера построения интерпретаторов сойдет.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/obasic/